# Editing Quantity in Cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So this is another post about updating the quantity in the cart!  Any one that I could find seemed to be outdated, so I apologize if this seems repetative.

But I am following along in Agile Web Development with Rails 4th edition book, and they were so kind as to leave editing the quantity as a 'challenge' and not show the answer :D.  Now as I'm trying to get it to work I'm having troubles.

Show in my views/cart/show.html.erb I have the following table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
<% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= form_for 'item', :url => {:controller => 'line_items', :action => 'update', id: item} do |f| %>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.number_field :qty, :value => item.qty %>
                    <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= item.product.name %></td>
        <td><%= item.size %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total Price</td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Yet when I click update I get either

> Unknown action
>
> The action '29' could not be found for LineItemsController

or

> Unknown action
>
> The action '35' could not be found for LineItemsController

even if I completely take out the id field.  I can deal with the update function on the controller side and getting it update properly - I want to figure that out on my own but I can't figure out what could possibly be generating these numeric actions and how I can fix it.  In short, what is producing this error and how can I fix it?  Is it perhaps related to the fact I have a line_item form in a cart view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it working - that I did was I tweaked the form header like so

```
  <%= form_for :item, :url => line_items_update_path(id: item.id) do |f| %>
```

I added the following line to my routes.rb

```
  get "line_items/update"
```

And added one line to my line_items_controller

```
  def update
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.qty = params[:item][:qty] #added this line here
```

For those who are having problems!

Answer (score 1):

do you check the 29 and 35 is either ur id or anything else? try to check with your database for LineItems , and how your controller look like?? and

```
<%= form_for 'item', :url => {:controller => 'line_items', :action => 'update', id: item} do |f| %>
```

you trying to update it in ajax way or ? when update the quantity, should it be using ajax if it's not mistaken (the book asked to do in that way right? )

Comment: It varies based on whether I include id: item or not.  If I include it, it comes up as 35 if not then it comes up as 29.

I am planning on using AJAX but taking it one step at a time.  If I move it to another page, under the line_items/edit path, it works beautifully, but for some reason when I have the form on this page then it gives me the error

Comment: So if I include id: item.id then it uses the line item id, if I dont then it is using the cart id to create the url to answer your question